# Minimum surface area for a given volume of prism with edges of integer length

Tags: c#, geometry, formula

If I have some `int volume`, how would I go about writing a method that returns `length`, `width`, and `height` (all ints) so that `length*width*height>=volume` and `2(width*length+height*length+height*width)` is as small as possible?

Basically, the smallest surface area (and the values that comprise it) for a given volume of a rectangular prism.

Also, ideally it would be able to set `length`, `width`, and/or `height` and they would remain fixed while solving the problem. For instance, calculate `width` and `height` while `volume=52` and `length=3`.

EDIT: I wrote this simple brute force to show me the answers I want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace surface_area_volume_ratio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Volume--\nSurace Area-Ratio : L, W, H");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            for (int volume = 1; volume < 200; volume++)
            {
                double dv=volume;
                List<double> ratios = new List<double>();
                List<int> surface = new List<int>();
                List<int> ls = new List<int>();
                List<int> ws = new List<int>();
                List<int> hs = new List<int>();
                for (int l = 1; l <= volume; l++)
                {
                    double dl = l;
                    for (int w = 1; w <= volume; w++)
                {
                    double dw = w;
                    for (int h = 1; h <= volume; h++)
                    {
                        double dh = h;
                        if (l * w * h >= volume)
                        {
                            int s = (2 * (l * w + l * h + w * h));
                            surface.Add(s);
                            ratios.Add(s/dv);
                            ls.Add(l);
                            ws.Add(w);
                            hs.Add(h);
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            double smallest=0;
            if (ratios.Count>0)
                smallest = ratios.Min();
                Console.WriteLine(volume+"--");
            for (int i = 0; i < ratios.Count; i++)
            {
                if (smallest==ratios[i])
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1} : {2}, {3}, {4}",surface[i],ratios[i],ls[i],ws[i],hs[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which shape are we talking about?

Comment: Add the solution you came up with for the problem and get help for implementation. That way you'll get a better idea of how your thoughts can be translated to c#

Comment: "No idea where to begin" => not ready to ask on Stack Overflow. If you don't know how to do it on paper, you need to figure that out first, maybe ask on a math Q+A site if you need help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming have links to types of problems you are looking for...

Comment: This can easily be solved using introductory calculus.

Comment: @B.K. I don't think introductory calculus considers discrete values like int...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov His original version of the question wasn't as specific.  There was no specification of shapes or that it MUST be an integer, unless I missed something.

Comment: @B.K. The "that returns length, width, and height *(all ints)*" was there in original version too... I've only moved it to title too as people seem not notice it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov fair enough, I must've missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate volume as such:

```
double volume = length * width * height;
```

Reverse this process with a cube root to get back to length width and height:

```
var val = Math.Pow(1000, ((double)1 / 3));
double length = val,
       width = val,
       height = val;
```

Also, an example of how to hard-code one of the values. All you do is devide the hard-coded value from the volume, and then do a square root to get the last two values:

```
double volume = 1000; //example volume
double length = 50; //<- example hard coded length
double val = Math.Sqrt(volume / length);
double width = val,
       height = val;
```

**I originally posted this without realizing that integer type was a condition of the question. I am leaving this code here for reference purposes.**

Comment: And? How this is solution for actual question "...all ints... surface is as small as possible"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Small as possible how? Be more specific. Provided you have the same volume, it will always be the same size. There is no smaller or larger cube generated by an identical volume. This will produce a cube with equal xyz values, so it is the smallest possible value for all three. Decreasing any one of the values will only increase another.

Comment: caesay - question requires all values to be int. This makes problem *much* harder - how your code finds set of int values as answer for 65 for example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute force solution:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int volume = 52;
            int l=0, w=0, h=0, minval=int.MaxValue;
            for (int length = 1; length <= volume; length++)
            {
                for (int width = 1; width <= volume; width++)
                {
                    for (int height = 1; height <= volume; height++)
                    {
                        if(length * width * height >= volume){
                            int area = 2*(length*width + width*height + length*height);
                            if(area < minval){
                                l=length;
                                w=width;
                                h=height;
                                minval = area;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("length = " + l + ", width= " + w + ", height = " + h);
        }
    }
}
```

This is to find the rectangular prism with integer lengths satisfying the conditions. If integer lengths are not required then the problem is trivial, refer [caesay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32217380/2136312).

*IMHO you should post your algorithm and your attempt at the solution then ask for corrections/ help. Stackoverflow shouldn't be used to get your entire work done for you.*

Comment: Note that similar  suggestion is already downvoted for some reason... Anyway brute-force is the easiest approach for relatively small numbers.

Comment: That suggestion just had code skeleton, it didn't contain anything useful. Please explain if you find anything wrong with the answer, I'll gladly make the edits.

Answer (score -2):

Start with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int volume = 0;
            int surfaceArea = 0;
            for (int length = 1; length < 100; length++)
            {
                for (int width = 1; width < 100; width++)
                {
                    for (int height = 1; height < 100; height++)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why this is helpful.

Comment: @caesay because it is really good starting point to the most basic approach and may as well be easier than real algorithm (for small numbers).